# How to just change the surface appearance of the transform object in paraview?

Tags: transform, colormap, paraview

I have a triangular sphere surface with two scalars on every point. In paraview, I transform the surface and get two new triangular spheres, see the following figure:

[image]

I want to change the colormap of the third one, but paraview will also change the first one. So is it possible to just change the colormap of the third one?

Comment: By default colormap are linked by name in ParaView. Which version of ParaView aur you using ?

Comment: @user1416930 My paraview version is 5.1.0 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one of the commenters said, color maps in ParaView are shared for all arrays of the same name. One workaround is to use the **Calculator** filter after your third object to change the name. Set the **Result Array Name** to a new name ("NewName" below) and set the expression to the existing name of your data array ("RTData" below).

[image]

Color the third object by this new array name. You can now change the color map for it and it will not affect the color map applied to the first object.

By the way, in ParaView 5.5, which is due out sometime in November, you will not have to use this workaround, but can instead designate the color map as unique to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify I have the same behaviour, however it is possible to colour the transformed dataset differently if you set the scalar using the scalar selection dropdown in the properties window.

[image: Colour by Scalar]